# Clientdataset 'index not found' error in nested dataset

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I am attempting to find a subset of records in a clientdataset by using a clone cursor to seek a records using an indexdef.  In the example below I have created  a button to implement the clone creation. The code works fine for a clientdataset named cdsData.  However if I nest cdsData in another dataset (cdsMaster) then the button code fails to find the indexDef.

The Form: *(including both clientdatasets showing both datasources and clientdatasets.  Omit dsMaster & cdsMAster in first unit example below)*

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 289
  ClientWidth = 554
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 32
    Top = 24
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Clone'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object dsMaster: TDataSource
    DataSet = cdsMaster
    Left = 56
    Top = 80
  end
  object cdsMaster: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    Left = 56
    Top = 144
  end
  object dsData: TDataSource
    DataSet = cdsData
    Left = 152
    Top = 88
  end
  object cdsData: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    Left = 152
    Top = 144
  end
end
```

The successful cdsData unit:

```
unit IndexFindTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    dsData: TDataSource;
    cdsData: TClientDataSet;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Disp, Lbl : string;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Clone: TClientDataset;
begin
  Clone := TClientDataset.Create(nil);
  try
    Clone.CloneCursor(cdsData,false);
    cdsData.IndexDefs.Update;
    clone.IndexName := cdsData.IndexDefs.find ('Lbl').Name;
    //..added code to select a range of records using the IndexDef
  finally
    clone.free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  disp := 'Item 1';
  lbl := 'a';
   with TStringField.Create(Self) do begin
    Name := 'MstrDisplays';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Displays';
    Size := 10;
    DataSet := cdsData;
  end;

   with TStringField.Create(Self) do begin
    Name := 'MstrLabel';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Label';
    Size := 10;
    DataSet := cdsData;
  end;


  with cdsData.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do begin
    Name := 'Lbl';
    Fields := 'Displays;Label';
    Options := [ixCaseInsensitive];
  end;
  cdsData.CreateDataSet;
end;

end.
```

The nested version that fails:

```
unit IndexFindTest2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    dsMaster: TDataSource;
    cdsMaster: TClientDataSet;
    Button1: TButton;
    dsData: TDataSource;
    cdsData: TClientDataSet;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Disp, Lbl : string;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Clone: TClientDataset;
begin
  Clone := TClientDataset.Create(nil);
  try
    Clone.CloneCursor(cdsData,false);
    cdsData.IndexDefs.Update;

    //Error generated in next line
    clone.IndexName := cdsData.IndexDefs.find ('Lbl').Name;

    //..added code to select a range of records using the IndexDef    
  finally
    clone.free;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  disp := 'Item 1';
  lbl := 'a';
   with TStringField.Create(Self) do begin
    Name := 'MstrTitle';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Title';
    Size := 10;
    DataSet := cdsMaster;
  end;
  with TDataSetField.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Name := 'MstrDisplay';
    FieldName := 'Displays';
    DataSet := cdsMaster;
  end;

  cdsData.DataSetField := TDataSetField(cdsMaster.FieldByName('Displays'));
  with TStringField.Create(Self) do begin
    Name := 'ClientNested';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Notes';
    Size := 10;
    DataSet := cdsData;
  end;

  with TStringField.Create(Self) do begin
    Name := 'kntLabel';
    FieldKind := fkData;
    FieldName := 'Label';
    Size := 10;
    DataSet := cdsData;
  end;

  cdsData.IndexDefs.Update;
  with cdsData.IndexDefs.AddIndexDef do begin
    Name := 'Lbl';
    Fields := 'Notes;Label';
    Options := [ixCaseInsensitive];
  end;
  cdsMaster.CreateDataSet;
end;
end.
```

When running the second program  I receive the error

> cdsData: index 'Lbl' not found.

The only difference I can identify between the two programs is the fact that cdsData is nested in the second version.  I found a note in CaryJensen's Delphi in Depth:clientDatasets 2nd edition (pg128) stating that the erro may occur and can be fixed using update, but no matter where in the sequence I apply the update, it does not work in this situation.

Can anyone shed light on this problem?  Are there additional steps with a nested dataset?

Comment: I've never used nested datasets so I am guessing here. The TDataSetField is another full dataset that can have multiple rows. I can't think of any way that the Lbl index can reference anything in the master dataset. From the cdsData view point there is no field called "Displays". If you call cdsData.FindField('Displays') after creating the dataset it will return Nil. You should not need Display part of that index anyway. When you are one master row all of the subitems would have the same value for display anyway. That's not useful for either a lookup or sort.

Comment: @MarkElder  Excellent catch re Displays. I changed some names when I wrote this example.  The 'Lbl' indexdef should have read 'Notes;Label'.  HOwever, when I make that change so that the indexdef is properly addressing cdsData fields, I still get the error.  I have edited the original question to correct this mistake.

Comment: I think it has to do with nested inactive indexes. If you set   cdsData.IndexName := 'Lbl'; somewhere in the create then the issue goes away. It worked for me both before or after calling .CreateDataSet. I have the ClientDataSets books 1st edition. See "Using Persistent Indexes" where it talks about the index not being created until the name is set (mine is on page 106). My guess is the nested field level clones are keeping active indexes but not all of the IndexDefs. The call to IndexDefs.Update does not seem to be needed if the index is already active.

Comment: I have it working if I substitute  `clone.IndexFieldNames := 'Display;Label';` for the errant code line.  I am using multiple indexes in the actual program so indexDef would have been preferable, but I can live with the workaround.  I suspect you are right about nested indexes. Thanks for your input.  Put your comment as an answer and I'll give it an upvote.